# Weights for unknown category in the population

Tags: r, survey, survey-weights

I have a dataset with survey responses where the variable gender has three categories: male, female and nonbinary, but the population dataset used to sample the individuals to send the survey has only categories male and female. Now I need to adjust for the weights, but I don't how to deal with nonbinary that is not present in the population dataset. In other words, I have to do raking, i.e.,  iterative post-stratification to match marginal distributions of a survey sample to known population margins, but I don't know the population margin for the nonbinary response to the gender question in the survey.

Comment: More details, please.

Comment: I edited the question.